# Insert/Update of XMLType with JPA

Tags: oracle, jpa, oracle11g, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have an oracle database with a column with XMLType. I have implemented a DescriptorCustomizer for it and I am using XMLType as my field type in the Entity.

Essentially I have:

```
@Entity
@Customizer(XmlCustomizer.class) 
public class ...... {
    .....
private XMLType xmlColumn;
    .....
}
```

This all works great for reading data from the database. But when it comes to persisting the data I am not sure what to do. I haven't found an easy way to create an XMLType object with xml in it. Most of the methods seem to ask for a connection which is pretty ugly. So what is it that I am missing or misunderstanding?

Thanks.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I do have it working with XMLType but like I said I have to pass a connection to the database which I can get from my EntityManager. Seems ugly though.

Comment: Is serializing Object to database as BLOB would be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest EclipseLink (2.4) seems to convert XMLType straight into String without the need for a customizer.

Answer (score 0):

XMLType is an Oracle JDBC type, so probably not the best type of field for an object.

You can map it to a String or a DOM Document instead, then you can write it.

Comment: It is my understanding that if I convert it to a String or DOM Document that I will hurt performance greatly. I am on the early stages of learning how JPA works and how the Oracle XMLType object  works but I believe if I have Lazy fetching, the XMLType object will only fetch elements as needed if I use the provided methods for extracting elements.

Comment: That depends on how big your xml document is.  You could make the attribute LAZY, so it is only fetched when accessed.  If you want to use the type directly you can get a JDBC Connection from the EntityManager using unwrap()

Comment: I was able to make my DescriptorCustomizer work well for XMLType but I never got it to work for String or Document. XMLType allows me to get a Document object so it isn't too bad. And yeah I plan on using a lazy fetcher. I did get the connection working using this code `java.sql.Connection conn = ((com.caucho.sql.UserConnection) entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class)).getDriverConnection()` since I am using Resin. Seems ugly but at this point I just want it to work.

Comment: Lazy fetching doesn't work for columns. Consider moving lob/blob to another table and set this 1-to-1 relationship lazy.